# Complex solutions to $z^n = a \times z^*$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having an issue with equations that include both the unknown complex number and its conjugate.  A particular one I'm working with is $z^4 = -27z^*$, where $z^*$ is the conjugate.  However I'm interested in a more general method.  I have tried one thing, but I think something is wrong about it:

Considering my particular question, I know that $z = r e^{i\theta}$, so my equation is:

$$r^4 e^{i4\theta} = -27re^{-i\theta}$$

My next step was to remove the conjugate from the right side by multiplying by $z$ itself, which gave me:

$$r^5e^{i5\theta} = -27r^2$$

This leads to a fifth order, which adds another root, so I feel that this isn't right, although I can solve this new equation by taking the fifth root and equating real and complex parts.  Is there a better way to approach this particular question, and these types of questions in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in the right track. Notice that $z = 0$ is a solution. If we consider that $z\neq 0$, one has that
\begin{align*}
r^{4}e^{i4\theta} = -27re^{-i\theta} \Longleftrightarrow r^{3}e^{i5\theta} = -27 \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
r^{3} = 27\\
5\theta = -\pi + 2k\pi
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I just needed confirmation that I wasn't way off.  I'll accept the answer once stack exchange allows me to